# Does the qmake includes pri files automatically in the pro file

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

Assume the following directory structure

```
project/project.pro
project/project.pri
```

In this case even if the project.pro file does not have a statement like (include project.pri). Does it gets included automatically by qmake.

In the qtcreator sources plugin directory

```
qt-creator/src/plugins/coreplugin
```

There is a coreplugin.pri file which is not included in the coreplugin.pro file

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly confident that it does not get included automatically, and I did a quick test with a .pro and a .pri file that had `message` calls in them to confirm this.

With regards to the files you're seeing in creator, it's not uncommon to have a .pri file that is designed for *other* .pro files to include so that you can use the project.

Comment: +1 for "it's not uncommon to have a .pri file that is designed for other .pro files to include so that you can use the project". This is a really useful way to avoid repetition on boiler-plate text on .pro files